# SQL-Query get best incidents by solution_time for each month

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have the following SQL-Query in Metabase:

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('month', "resolvedAt") AS "resolvedAt",
  (CAST(avg("solution_time") AS float) / CASE WHEN 3600.0 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE 3600.0 END) AS "Average Resolution Time",
  12 AS "Minium",
  8 AS "Expected"
FROM "custom_Incident"
RIGHT JOIN "ims_Incident" ON "incident" = "ims_Incident"."id"
WHERE {{resolveAt}}
  AND {{assigned_group_name}}
  AND {{service}}
  AND {{incident_type}}
  AND "statusDetail" = 'Closed'
  AND "ims_Incident"."uid" NOT IN
    (SELECT "uid"
     FROM "ignore_Incident")
  AND "ims_Incident"."uid" IN
    (SELECT "incident_id"
     FROM "custom_Incident"
     WHERE "custom_Incident"."incident_id" in
         (SELECT "uid"
          FROM "ims_Incident"
          WHERE {{resolveAt}}
            AND {{assigned_group_name}}
            AND {{service}}
            AND {{incident_type}}
            AND "statusDetail" = 'Closed'
            AND "ims_Incident"."uid" NOT IN
              (SELECT "uid"
               FROM "ignore_Incident"))
     ORDER BY "solution_time"
     LIMIT {{take_into_account}})
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "ims_Incident"."resolvedAt")
```

And I want to get the best ... let`s say 100 ... Incidents orderd by "solution_time" PER MONTH. So now I get the best with {{take_into_account}} (100) for the hole timeperiod of {{resolveAt}} but I want to split the {{resolveAt}} timeperiod (maybe 3 month) and for each of the month I want to get the best 100 Incidents orderd by "solution_time". So with 3 month there would be 300 incidents with {{take_into_account}} = 100 there would be 100 for each month.

How can I do that?

Comment: `WHEN 3600.0 = 0` -- Huh?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).